# select a private page as parent for another private page

Tags: pages, child-pages

I am trying to build a customer portal however the private page is not showing in the parent drop-down  (The drop-down at the right bottom of page settings under page attributes). Both the parent and child pages need to be private so that only logged in users can access it.

I have tried this code which didn't work for me.

```
/**
 * Add private/draft/future/pending pages to parent dropdown.
 */
function wps_dropdown_pages_args_add_parents( $dropdown_args, $post = NULL ) {
    $dropdown_args['post_status'] = array( 'publish', 'private', );
    return $dropdown_args;
}

add_filter( 'page_attributes_dropdown_pages_args', 'wps_dropdown_pages_args_add_parents' );
add_filter( 'quick_edit_dropdown_pages_args', 'wps_dropdown_pages_args_add_parents' );
```

Comment: what is your code to retrieve the dropdown list?

Comment: @simongcc I have not added any code from my end I did try one. I have edited the answer with the same. The parent drop-down gets populated itself when we create/edit a page (The dropdown at the right bottom of page settings under page attributes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following conditions is assumed to make it working

- **Classic Editor** is in use, since **Gutenberg/Block Editor** is rendered by Javascript, it requires another solutions and so far I am not sure if there is override option yet.

For the code you have shown, it does not work because the number of arguments for [add_filter()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/) is not specified.
By default, only 1 argument is used. To use more than 1 argument, it is necessary to specify.

#### Code correction (The asker's code is for Classic Editor)

The following is tested, it works for any post types even custom post types.
The following code is proved to work by putting in theme's functions.php

```
/**
 * Add private/draft/future/pending pages to parent dropdown.
 */
function wps_dropdown_pages_args_add_parents( $dropdown_args, $post = NULL ) {
    $dropdown_args['post_status'] = array( 'publish', 'private', );
    return $dropdown_args;
}

add_filter( 'page_attributes_dropdown_pages_args', 'wps_dropdown_pages_args_add_parents', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'quick_edit_dropdown_pages_args', 'wps_dropdown_pages_args_add_parents' );
```

---

#### Disable the Block Editor (for Classic Editor's method)

In case anyone would like to disable the Gutenberg editor for testing the above code, you may put the following code in theme's functions.php

```
add_filter( 'use_block_editor_for_post_type', 'sing_use_block_editor_for_post_type', 10, 2 );
function sing_use_block_editor_for_post_type( $can_use, $post_type ) {
    switch ( $post_type ) {
        case 'custom_post_types':
        case 'post':
        case 'page':
            $can_use = false;
            break;

        default:
            $can_use = true;
            break;
    }

    return $can_use;
}
```

---

#### Override method for Gutenberg/Block Editor

Please use the filter
[rest_{$this->post_type}_query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_this-post_type_query/) to override the query

Because Gutenberg is using Rest API to load data, page list is one of them.
The following is tested on the same test pages with Parent and Child both private. The following code is proved to work by placing in theme's functions.php

```
add_filter( 'rest_page_query', 'test_rest_page_query', 10, 2);
function test_rest_page_query( $args, $request ) {
    // please add your own logic such as screen id check logic

    $args['post_status'] = array( 'publish', 'private' );
    return $args;
}
```

Comment: It's not working. I am still not getting the private page as option. This function needs to be added in function.php file right?

Comment: Yes, I just added to the functions.php and it works immediately. I have created a private page and assign it to a child. BTW, this method is only working for classic editor. For Gutenberg/Block Editor, it requires different solutions. Are you using Gutenberg editor? If so, you could disable the Gutenberg editor to test.

Comment: is your child page also private? Yes I am using Gutenberg editor. Ok so other than changing the editor there is no solution?

Comment: Yes. The child page is also private. I am trying and looking into the source code to see if there is any chance to get it done.

Comment: @ArushiRajput I have added the solutions for Gutenberg and proved to work with a test using same private pages setup.

Comment: It worked. Thanks

Comment: Could you make a plugin from this? This would be very useful. There is an unmaintained plugin that hadn't been updated for 5 years (and which doesn't support Gutenberg): https://wordpress.org/plugins/inclusive-parents/

Comment: @strarsis Thanks for your interest and comment. It is a good idea but I will need to consider a bit because maintaining a plugin is not a trivial task which needs persistency checkup and regular update, support with appropriate compatibility checking.

Answer (score 1):

A little security and scope tweak to @arushi-rajput 's snippet:

```php
/**
 * Show all parents, regardless of post status. (for Gutenburg Editor)
 */

add_filter( 'rest_page_query', 'test_rest_page_query', 10, 2);
function test_rest_page_query( $args, $request ) {
    // Check if user has the 'edit_pages' capability
    if ( current_user_can( 'edit_pages' ) ) {
        $args['post_status'] = array( 'publish', 'private', 'draft', 'pending', 'future' );
    } else {
        // For other users, only show 'publish' status
        $args['post_status'] = array( 'publish' );
    }
    return $args;
}
```